# From a high level programming perspective, what is the major difference between C# and F#?

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming

I'm aware that they both use different programming paradigms, but from a high level perspective apart from differing syntax it seems most basic tasks can be achieved in similar fashion.

I only say this because when I've previously touched functional programming languages such as Haskell, writing code for basics tasks was (at first) difficult, frustrating, and required a completely different mindset.

For example the following took some time to get to grips with using recursive syntax:

```
loop :: Int -> IO ()
loop n = if 0 == n then return () else loop (n-1)
```

Where as an F# loop is recognisable and understable almost immediately:

```
let list1 = [ 1; 5; 100; 450; 788 ]
for i in list1 do
   printfn "%d" i
```

When C# programmers start learning F# they are advised to completely re-think their thought pattern (which was definitely required for Haskell), but I've now written several F# programs dealing with conditions, loops, data sets etc to perform practical tasks, and I'm wondering where the 'different-paradigm' barrier really kicks in?

Hopefully someone will be able to solve my confusion.

Comment: `let rec loop n = if n = 0 then () else loop (n - 1)`

Comment: Programers.StackExchanage would be the place for this type of question, though I suspect the answer would be that you are a born programmer, where as others are cookie cutter program by numbers types.

Comment: "What can C# do that F# cannot? NullReferenceException!" :)

Comment: @AlexeyRaga `(null : string).Length`

Comment: @RamonSnir how often in your F# code you would write something like that? :) You should explicitly set or declare something to null here. In the real life NRE happens only if you use non-F# code (perhaps libs written in C#). So in the real life in F# people do not check for null everywhere when in C# we do it everywhere a lot.

Comment: @AlexeyRaga any non-obvious code uses .NET libraries and I/O. `null` exists in F#, and cannot be simply ignored because "most cases of idiomatic F# don't use `null`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wThe main difference when the barrier kicks in is when people have to think in terms of functions, not in terms of objects.

Yes, it is totally possible to do object-oriented code in F#, and in this matter there is not that much of a difference between these two besides syntax. But that's not the point when using F#, even if F# allows you do to it.

The barrier kicks in when developers start solving problems in a functional way.

Here are the some of the topics that are new for C#/OO developers when learning F#/FP

- Pattern matching. Sometimes people have hard times comprehending its usefulness.
- Tail recursion (and the "recursive" way of solving problems)
- Discriminated unions (people still try to look at them as to hierarchy of classes, IEquatable/IComparable implementations, etc instead of just thinking declaratively)
- The "unit" value over "void".
- Partial application (gets a bit easier as latest versions of C# allows us to deal with Funcs, but as it looks ugly not many do)
- The whole concept of values over variables (including immutability)

The main difference between C# and F# is that F# gives you all this, and it makes sense to take it and use it for good.
However, yes, it is still possible writing "Csharpish" code in F# without kicking any barrier except that in this case one will hate F# for its syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit misleading. From a very high-level perspective, pretty much all programming language are equivalent. They are all turing-complete and as such, allow you to solve the same set of problems.

From a still high-level, but more concrete perspective, C# and F# differ in so far, as F#'s functionality is a superset of C#'s. (please, do not flame me for this, I know it is not true, strictly speaking, but it gives a picture)

F# being a .net language, it inherits .net's object model and in the object-oriented subset is therefore very similar to C#, with a more lightweight syntax due to better type inference.

However, F# also supports two other paradigms:

- functional programming: F# "variables", they are in fact called values, are immutable by default and as such a c# style `int i = 0; i = i+1;` looks very differently in F#, because you need to allow for mutability explicitly `let mutable i = 0; i <- i + 1;`. So if you look at the functional subset, F# is, in fact a lot closer to Haskell than it is to C#.
- imperative programming: You can also write F# code in a script-oriented style, without classes, modules, etc. Just a pure script, and in this case it also looks very differently from C#.

Your example used loops similar in style to how you would write C# code and therefore it felt similar.

If you do a very small change, however, you can achieve the same thing in a way that is already quite different from C#. `[ 1; 5; 100; 450; 788 ] |> List.iter (printfn "%d")`

The reason why people tend to claim you need to change the way how you think about problems, is because the incentive of F#, for a C# programmer, usually is the *functional subset*, not the object-oriented one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't done too much Haskell?

How is, for example,

```
let list1 = [ 1, 5, 100, 450, 788 ]
forM_ list1 printStrLn
```

less recognzable?

If you like, you can even have an alias `for` for `forM_`

Comment: It gets even more obvious when you turn it into `forM_ list1 $ \i -> printf "%d" i`, particularly with proper indentation.